# count the number of elements of each type in a pandas column

Tags: pandas, count, dtype

I am new to pandas.

I have a column with the object dtype that contains floats and strings.

I would like to count the number of each in the column.

I figured out a way to do it:

```
len([v for v in list(df["ColumnA"]) if type(v)==float])
len([v for v in list(df["ColumnA"]) if type(v)==str])
```

But is there a more direct way to do this?

Ideally, I'd prefer to be able to do something like:

`df["ColumnA"].dtypes`

and have the output be:

```
float: 103,544
str:     2,767
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked:

```
df["ColumnA"].apply(type).value_counts()

<class 'str'>        2767
<class 'float'>    103544
Name: ColumnA, dtype: int64
```

Comment: good, what will you do with that count? It seems wrong to have different types in the same column...

Comment: I didn't create the files. I am used to R, and didn't know there could be different types in the same column in pandas. I was getting unexpected results, and now I know why. Now, I am using the code above to check the columns, rather than assume each column has only one type.

Comment: I still don't understand the last line ```Name: ColumnA, dtype: int64```, because when I run ```df.dtypes``` it says ```ColumnA   object```, so I don't know where the ```int64``` comes from.

Comment: the result of `.value_counts()` is a series itself, of dtype `int64`, which has nothing to do with the df dtypes

Comment: did you try `df.convert_dtypes()` or `df.ColumnA = df.ColumnA.astype(np.float)`? depending on what you have on the data, it might suffice to change the whole column to a numeric dtype

Comment: It turned out that some of the “codes”, which were mostly integers, started with an “E”. I had assumed they were all integers.